# Aptana Studio Installer Error

Tags: installation, aptana

Anyone know how to work around the following error?

When I attempt to run the Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.6.1, I get the following error:

```
[SEH_AV_WRITE_BADPTR] ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at address [0x77582b1b]
```

Comment: After adding some windows updates to my new laptop, the installer is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same snag - Aptana was bought by AppCelerator, then they were bought by someone else - I called, and they say that Aptana is no longer being supported.

Too bad as I used it 2 years ago and thought it was great.